# How to display all results of a search in vim

Tags: vim

When searching string with notepad++, new window opens and shows find 
results. I want to use this feature in vim. After googling I found out some suggestions:

```
vimgrep /<pattern>/ %
copen
```

It is possible to create mapping which do those two commands. Pattern should be the current word: may be  cword keyword in vim?

Comment: note that if you do `vimgrep ... %`, it may not work on a unamed buffer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The requirement is actually easy. but to get user inputted pattern, you need a function.

```
function! FindAll()
    call inputsave()
    let p = input('Enter pattern:')
    call inputrestore()
    execute 'vimgrep "'.p.'" % |copen'
endfunction
```

if you want to have a mapping, add this line:

```
nnoremap <F8> :call FindAll()<cr>
```

but as I commented under your question. `%` may not work for unamed buffer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can I use the mouse the navigate over search result. i.e. navigate over search result by clicking  on the <file_name>|<file_number>.

Comment: @VardanHovhannisyan for the mouse operation.. I am not sure, I seldom use mouse when I am with vim. but I could check for you when I got time. For the word under cursor. pressing `<c-r><c-w>` in command line will give you that.. in fact sehe has this in his answer.

Comment: @VardanHovhannisyan double clicking on the entry in quickfix window will jump to that line here. I have `set mouse=a` in my `.vimrc`

Answer (score 5):

I suggest lvimgrep (so you can use quickfix for :make)

```
:nnoremap <F6> :lvimgrep /\M\<<C-R><C-W>\m\>/ **/*.[ch]pp **/Makefile | lopen<CR>
```

Also, if you *just* wanted to find in the current file:

```
:g/<pattern>/
```

will invoke 'print' (default command) on each matching line.

```
:v//               " non-matching lines
:g//-1             " lines preceding the matching line
:g//-1,+1          " lines around the matching line
```

etc.

:global is far more useful:

```
 :g/foo/ join       " join all lines containing foo
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks for help. I try it, but it's give the error message:
    Error detected while processing /home/student/.vimrc:
    line   30:
    E488: Trailing characters:  lopen<CR>

Comment: I find using `:number` (or `:nu` for short) combined with `:g` to be quite nice.

Comment: @PeterRincker my weapon of choice would be even shorter: `:g//#`

Answer (score 1):

Those two commands can be shortened and chained: `:vim foo %|co`. You can pull the word under the cursor like this: `:vim <C-r><C-w> %|co`.

Here is a quick normal mode mapping that you can use to list all the occurrences of the word under your cursor in the quickfix window:

```
nnoremap <F6> :vimgrep /<C-r><C-w>/j % <bar> cwindow<cr>
```

---

You can also use `:il[ist] foo` to display a list of all the occurrences of `foo` or `[I` to display the same list for the word under your cursor.

When the list is displayed, use `:{line number}` to jump to the corresponding line.