# vim bookmark all search results

Tags: vim

Is it possible in vim  to bookmark all search results like in notepad++? i.e. all search results are stored on the bottom window. So it's no needs  to search what you are already have  searched.

Comment: I don't get it. if you search `foo`, and there are 50 `foo` in your current buffer, you want to open a window just show 50 `foo`s? also, if you want to mark all search reasults, say, you found 50 results, how do you mark them with vim mark? what do  you really want?

Comment: This how it's look like in notepad++ [link]http://www.google.ru/search?hl=ru&newwindow=1&q=notepad%2B%2B+search+results+window&biw=1344&bih=705&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&ei=BmRlUZ_wLIzdsga294CoBA#imgrc=lPEnsxpcDTilJM%3A%3B6wDy0O9XQhe1kM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fnpp-community.tuxfamily.org%252FImages%252FScreenshots%252Fsrwindow.png%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fnpp-community.tuxfamily.org%252Fdocumentation%252Fnotepad-user-manual%252Fsearching%252Fsearch-results%3B486%3B269

Comment: look this question from you, it does what you need, doesn't it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15906029

Comment: No it's not. That question has been asked by me,    but it's was for single search result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you search the current buffer via

```
:vimgrep /{pattern}/ %
```

instead of `/{pattern}`, Vim will store the matches in the *quickfix list*. You can open a window with the results via `:copen`, and select a match with <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This was mainly done for compiler errors, but it's useful for search results, too. The nice thing is (and here comes the answer to your question) that Vim stores the last ten lists, and you can recall them with `:colder` and `:cnewer`.

Comment: Thanks. This what I am looking for. Can I see all searches at the same time, and navigate through it by mouse.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what 'storing search results' means, but if you type `q/`in normal mode, you get a pop-up window with your latest searches that you can even edit before executing them again.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following code to search the word under cursor and to get the list displayed in the quickfix list at the bottom of the screen :

```
noremap <Leader>g :grep<space><C-r><C-w><CR>:copen<CR>
```

You can adjust where and what you want to search trough `set grepprg` in your `.vimrc`, this is using the system `grep` rather than the Vim built-in command.